# Database time format change

Tags: php, database, time

For my database time, I have the following:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Canada/Mountain');
$comment_date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

 $data = array(                         
        'comment_date' => $comment_date         
    );
```

But I am getting `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as the results.

I am trying to show the time in "1 min" or "20 hr" or "4 days" format.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be using MySQL.  Assuming this, change

`$comment_date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());`

to

`$comment_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');`

and it should retain the correct date when you save it to the database.  The reason is that MySQL expects the datetime in the latter format.

I'm not sure what you mean by `I am trying to show the time in "1 min" or "20 hr" or "4 days" format`. You can use the MySQL DATE_FORMAT() function to format the date when you extract it from the database.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format for details on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that PHP does not support the `Canda/Mountain` time zone.

For a list of supported timezones, see the [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need two fixes. First is timezone as you are using an invalid one. The preferred timezone may be Canada/Saskatchewan. (Change it according to your zone by viewing the list of supported zones [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php))

Secondly, you are using an invalid date format for MySQL. At the end, your code should look like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Canada/Saskatchewan');
$comment_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

 $data = array(                         
        'comment_date' => $comment_date         
    );
```